# Error trying to connect to TFS from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to connect to a `TFS` 2010 Server via `SQL Server Management Studio 2008`.  The Source Control has a .sql file I need to open, edit, then commit back to source control.

From `SSMS`, I go to File > Open From Source Control...

I connect the TFS server and can browse to the project's folders successfully:

[image]

However, when I click OK, this error message is returned:

[image]

If I connect to TFS via `Visual Studio 2008`, I can browse the folders on the server, but SSMS will not allow me to.  Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: I am guessing the source control plugin requires an SSMS Project or SSMS Solution file to be present (*.ssmssln or *.ssmssqlproj). Note, these are not the same as VS db project sln/proj files and are created in SSMS through File > New > Project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Pero's comments are right, if there are database projects there (presume they have a folder for each project under your DatabaseProject folder) you'd need to select a folder that has a valid *.ssmssln or *.ssmssqlproj in.

Remember that SSMS will only open SQL Script solutions created in SSMS, not SSDT database projects. I don't think there are any projects that you can open in both SSMS and SSDT/Visual Studio.